# How to format the output of generated report using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I have written the VBA code to color any figure above 15, but it display rows above 15 as red including other rows.
Below is the VBA code

```
Sub FillCells()Dim lRow As Long, lColumn As Long
'Using Cells property to refer to range
'Loop through rows
For lRow = 1 To 10
'Loop through columns
For lColumn = 1 To 5
Cells(lRow, lColumn).Value = lRow * lColumn
Next lColumn
Next lRow
Call ColorCells
End Sub

Sub ColorCells()Dim rng As Range
Dim lRow As Long, lColumn As Long
Set rng = Range("A1:E10")
For lRow = 1 To rng.Rows.Count
For lColumn = 1 To rng.Columns.Count


If rng.Cells(lRow, lColumn).Value > 15 Then
rng.Cells(lRow, lColumn).Font.ColorIndex = 3
Else
rng.Cells(lRow, lColumn).Font.ColorIndex = 1
End If
Next lColumn
Next lRow
End Sub
```

Which shows the output as

[image]

But my query is how to get only rows above 15 with red color

**UPDATE:**

as per this [rejected edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/4721001), desired output is:

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what is the problem. As per your image all cells with value `>15` are red. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: As from image you can see that i am getting row 1 to row 3 which contains cell <15 including rows all cells with value >15 are red but i want only rows with at least any cells with value > 15 are red means only row 4 to row 10 in above image

Comment: user3591858, see my updated answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPD:**

```
Sub ColorCells()
    Dim rng As Range, rw As Range, c As Range
    Dim rngToDel As Range

    Set rng = Range("A1:E10")
    For Each rw In rng.Rows
        If Application.CountIf(rw, ">" & 15) > 0 Then
            For Each c In rw.Cells
                If c.Value > 15 Then
                    c.Font.ColorIndex = 3
                Else
                    c.Font.ColorIndex = 1
                End If
            Next c
        Else
            If rngToDel Is Nothing Then
                Set rngToDel = rw
            Else
                Set rngToDel = Union(rngToDel, rw)
            End If
        End If
    Next

    If Not rngToDel Is Nothing Then rngToDel.EntireRow.Delete
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image]

Comment: Thanks for solving my query